# How install and boot Ubuntu 10.04 from an iSCSI target?

Tags: ubuntu, iscsi

Is it possible to install Ubuntu 10.04 to an [iSCSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISCSI) target and boot from it?

For example [Etherboot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPXE) allows to boot Windows 2003 Server from iSCSI:

[image]

I'm thinking about a diskless computer, of course with Etherboot placed on a floppy.

Do live examples exist?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a truly diskless environment, I suggest you use an HBA (HOST BUS ADAPTER).  IntelPRO1000 is a cheap network card that I use for iSCSI remote target booting. You could use a small drive to bootstrap an iSCSI session with, but it would be more trouble than it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to install Ubuntu 10.04 to an iSCSI target and boot from it?
>   ...
>   Do live examples exist?

Yes and yes.  A blow-by-blow install using OpenSolaris ZFS targets can be found at:

http://opensolaris.org/jive/thread.jspa?messageID=502331

Comment: the link is dead D: